# Need to Add Context menu on outlook ReportItem (In terms of outlook users 'Read Receipt')

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, office-2013

I am trying to develop Outlook Add-in for Microsoft Outlook 2013. I have already added context menu on outlook MailItem, DocumentItem. I have done some research regarding context menu on ReportItem (in terms of outlook 'Read Receipt') but I didn't get any idea for the same.

Can anyone help me out to create context menu on outlook Read Receipt (ReportItem) ?

for more details, I have attached few of images regarding my code.

[image: Image represent what I actually want.]

This is my Ribbon XML Code
[image: Ribbon XML code]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after spending lot's of time on this research and I got solution.

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
```

Using above idmso, I am able to add context menu on Outlook ReportItem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to find a correct idMso value. Try the following markup:

```
<contextMenus>    
   <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReportItem">
      <button id="MyContextMenuReportItem"
        label="ContextMenuReportItem"
        onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
   </contextMenu>  
</contextMenus>
```

Read more about that in the [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I have just putted your code in my project but still i am not able to add context menu in ReportItem.

Comment: I have updated my description with more details. You can get all the information from images. 

Thanks.